# How to fix Django models migrate error for image field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am putting an image field in a model called Students. Everything is working fine until I put an image field into the model. I am getting the following even I put blank and null as True. It should work fine. Following is the detail information.

## Error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__genius_students.image
```

This is the model

## models.py

```
class Students(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=1, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Date of Birth')
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

I had tried many things like clearing cache and cookie. But No luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733221/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-products-product-ima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the migrations folder and delete manually files that have 000*_lastAction_blah-blah type of name, you can delete, probably all, but 0001_initial.py file. After that run ./manage.py make migrations app_you_are_updateing, it should update your database.

Comment: good to hear that. can you mark my answer as accepted..?

It would be helpful for other folks so that they get to know that this is a working solution. :-)