# Django REST with pytest fixture integrity error

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django, django-fixtures

I am trying to create a fixture with pytest, but when I run it, I get the following error:

**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id**

I found information on it, but I am not sure how to handle it when it comes to fixtures.

My code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def client(db):
    api_client = APIClient()
    token = Token.objects.get_or_create(user__username='testuser')
    api_client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token.key)
    return api_client


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_get_list_test(client):
    url = reverse('api/lists')
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, i don't think your error related to pytest here.
I think the main issue here related to django db migrations [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733221/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-products-product-ima)

So first, Make sure you fix it, regardless to any framework (pytest)

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id
```

And after you have successfully validated that the error passed away (check manually also), try to run the fixture.