# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_users.key_value_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Here i have two models Keys and Users i am creating POST API so i got encounter with this Error .

`UserModel.py:`

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
       vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
       key_value = models.ForeignKey(KeyTable, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
       username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="username", unique=True)
       password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       hardware_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
       created_by = models.DateField(verbose_name="created_by", auto_now_add=True)

       USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
       REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['password', 'hardware_id']

       is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
       is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_role_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
       is_role_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)

       def __str__(self):
             return self.username

       objects = UserManager()
```

`KeyModel.py:`

```
class KeyTable(models.Model):
      key_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, auto_created=True)
      key_value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      issue_date = models.DateField(max_length=100)
      expiry_date = models.DateField()
      status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      license_tenure = models.IntegerField()

      def __str__(self):
          return self.key_value
```

`KeySerializer:`

```
class KeySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model: Keys
         fields = ['key_id', 'key_value', 'issue_date', 'expiry_date', 'status', 'license_tenure']
```

`Error Encounters:`

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_users.key_value_id
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: If you really need your post gone, flag for moderator intervention. Do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set `null=True` and `blank=True` in the model field which is causing you an error
or you can delete the app and create it again with the same code this trick can also work.

But if you do not find solution then you can find several solutions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733221/django-db-utils-integrityerror-not-null-constraint-failed-products-product-ima)